# Unable to activate Implicit Grant & Hybrid Flows using the Az module cmds in PowerShell because the `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` param is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, microsoft-entra-id, powershell-az-module

I am in the process of transitioning from the Azure module to Az module commands to create an App registration and enable Implicit Grant. However, I have encountered a few parameters that are not available in the Az module.

Azure Module Script:

```
 
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <<TenantId>>
 
$appName = "<<AppName>>"
$redirectUris = @("https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName")
$secretName = "secretKey"

$App = (New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $appName `
-ReplyUrls $redirectUris `
-Homepage "https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName" `
-IdentifierUris "https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName"`
-Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $true -PublicClient $false
)
 
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AccountEnabled $true -AppId $App.AppId -DisplayName $appName
```

Below is Az module Script:

```
$appName = "<<AppName>>"
$redirectUris = @("https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName")
$secretName = "secretKey"
$App = (New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName `
-ReplyUrls $redirectUris `
-Homepage "https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName" `
-IdentifierUris "https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName"`
)
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $App.AppId
```

The documentation I am referring to for Az module commands is as follows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-11.1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-0.10.0

Is there an alternative method in the Az module PowerShell to enable "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow"?

I need to choose the options highlighted below using an Az module script.

[image]

[image]

Expected for Expose an API option is like below
[image]

Comment: Read following : https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **activate** Implicit Grant & Hybrid Flows using the **`Az`** module commands, you can make use of below updated script:

```
$appName = "<<AppName>>"
$redirectUris = @("https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName")
$secretName = "secretKey"
$App = (New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName `
-ReplyUrls $redirectUris `
-Homepage "https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName" `
-IdentifierUris "https://mspmecloud.onmicrosoft.com/$appName"`
-Web @{
    ImplicitGrantSetting = @{
        EnableAccessTokenIssuance = $true
        EnableIdTokenIssuance = $true
    }
}
)
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $App.AppId
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, application created successfully with *Implicit Grant & Hybrid Flows* **enabled** like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[New-AzADApplication (Az.Resources) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-11.1.0#notes)

Comment: Hi @Sridevi
Thank you for your assistance. Is there an Azure command (Az command) available to add scope to expose an API?

Comment: Could you post a new question with more details regarding this requirement and share link here?